# Install Laravel on current project with custom framework

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, frameworks

I need help and opinion.

I plan to develop API for the mobile application. Currently, using the custom framework, which follow the MVC structure. My issue right now is I am trying to make API for mobile which include all the Authentication, routing, etc. so its better for me to install Laravel in subdirectories of the current project, or continue from the project and create own API, routing, authentication, etc.)

What are the best methods?

Comment: Don't do that. Use laravel and it's existing feature. Because laravel already prebuilt it. So why you cost more time

Comment: Previous coding must be keep, I need to continue by adding Mobile APi @ArifulIslam so does use laravel is better? I do admit if I am still using the current work, I need to create everything from scratch. need to make a new routing, add the authentication..

Comment: If you have existing code, you can add in new laravel app. But little work should be done.  It will be a good idea for managing your all code from single application. laravel has now more support as well as feature

Comment: I would recommend you to install laravel and move all the code you currently have to laravel. You will save a lot of problems and the development will be faster.

Comment: I still considering this method, but would it required a lot of time to change from current working code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel is a modular framework and each component can be installed/used separately. Here is a repository of examples of how to get started with each component: https://github.com/mattstauffer/Torch

Comment: But I need change all the current working code, as Web already have all the need Function and modules, so I need to change my current working, I worry if this would required a lot of task

Comment: @MuhammadFaizAbdullah you can install Laravel routing and pass your `/api` routes to Laravel instead of your current framework. From there you can handle anything as a full Laravel application with Controllers, Models, Eloquent, etc.

Comment: Agree, I think I will do, as all the commentor suggest which is to install Laravel. Thank you all